# Using JS is there a shorthand for multiple if else conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a shorter way to have multiple if else conditions?

```
if( suffix != 'jpg' && suffix != 'jpeg' && suffix != 'png' && suffix != 'gif'){

    console.log('not an image.');

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an **array** can be seen as a shorthand, though it does add (negligible IMHO) overhead:

```
if (['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'].indexOf(suffix) === -1) {
  console.log('not an image.');
}
```

Edit: even shorter with **RegExp** :

```
if (!/jpe?g|png|gif/.test(suffix)) {
  console.log('not an image.');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than an Array with *indexOf*, you can use an ojbect with *in* or *hasOwnProperty*:

```
if (suffix in {jpg:'', jpeg:'', png:'', gif:''})
```

or

```
if ({jpg:'', jpeg:'', png:'', gif:''}.hasOwnProperty(suffix))
```

An object approach works well if you can make use of the object for other things.

Comment: I like the top one, but what is the opposite of `in` because I think u got it backwards ;)?  `out` didn't work.

Comment: There's no `out`, you have to negate the condition: `if (!suffix in ...)`

Comment: @Greg I tried `if (!suffix in {jpg:'', jpeg:'', png:'', gif:''}){...` but no dice.

Comment: `!suffix in` negates the truthy status of *suffix*, you need to `if (!(... in ...))`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not shorter but for all case statement lovers:

```
switch(suffix){
   case 'jpg':
   case 'jpeg':
   case 'png':
   case 'gif':
       break;
   default:
       console.log('not an image.');
       break;
}
```